# Is there a Wordpress Event Manager that links with your user database?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, plugins, customization, events

I'm presently moving my site from a different CMS.  Geeklog to Wordpress.  They have an event plugin that I used which is very simple.  This is it...  http://www.portalparts.com/staticpages/index.php?page=glEventMgr&query=event

I run comedy open mics and everyone on the website is a comedian.  They all have a login.  The ones out there for Wordpress are great, but they don't seem to tie in with your user database.  On this plugin above for the other CMS they were able to login, click an event and register for it with one more click.  I could set a limit on how many could sign up, they could unregister themselves, Email registrants etc...  No forms to fill out, nothing but logging in and making a couple clicks.  I've been searching through all the WP event plugins and none seem to do this.  They all make you fill out fields to register.  If anyone knows of a plugin that does what I'm looking for or can help in any way, please let me know! 
Thanks,
B

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple suggestions I have for you:

1. If you are a programmer and you can adapt [**this code that associates users with custom post types**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/commenting-in-user-profile-page/6165#6165) you might be able to get what you need.
2. You may also want to look at [**membership plugins**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/938/plugins-to-enable-subscriptions-of-digital-assets/950#950) as they may give you some of the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Custom Post Types feature to build your own version with exactly the options you need, a good starting point can be found here:

http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/custom-post-types-events-pt1/
http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/how-to-custom-post-types-for-events-pt-2/

Answer (score 0):

This my favourite events manager plugin 
http://gigpress.com/
not sure if and how it handles registration however

Answer (score 0):

I believe Event Espresso does... http://eventespresso.com/